# Is it possible to bind to a port that has a entry for DNAT in iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, netfilter

I have added a DNAT entry (in the host) for a port (say 30001) in `PREROUTING` using `iptables`

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 30001 -j DNAT --to-destination <my guest vm ip>:80
```

Note: Above I have tried a port forwarding technique to allow ingress to guest vm.

Is it possible for a host process to bind to the port `30001` after applying the above rule? Will Linux allow this or block by saying it is already in use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, binding a port is part of the network stack, which is separate from *netfilter* where *iptables* belongs to. *netfilter* will not care or be aware of this new listening port and the network stack will not be informed that there will be something special about it done in its back later.

So it's fine to have a process bind to port 30001/tcp. It won't be reachable from remote with your rule, but will still be usable locally: a local (non-routed) access from the host to itself follows the chain *OUTPUT* for emitting, then when it's looped back, arrives directly in *INPUT* without hitting *PREROUTING*, so your *nat/PREROUTING* rule would not be executed in this case.

This [schematic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) should help understand how it's working for the DNAT / routed case (the non-routed local case isn't shown as clearly though). A remote access would follow *PREROUTING* -> routing decision -> *INPUT* -> local process, but in your case with your DNAT rule it will take the path *PREROUTING* -> routing decision -> *FORWARD* -> ... so will not reach the local process. So as long you don't add the equivalent rule in *nat/OUTPUT*, there's still an use for this case. In any case, usable or not, you can still bind to this port.

Comment: Is there any way to restrict local process from using DNAT ruled ports. I am asking this because if the local process is not aware of this rule then for example if I use FTP in active mode it will choose a random port for data transfer, If that chose the DNAT ruled port it will be the issue right?

Comment: 1/ don't DNAT to ports in the dynamic range (32768-60999) used by local processes to avoid surprises 2/ once a flow is tracked, it won't be NATed again. So a local host client establishing an outgoing connection using source port 30001/tcp will not get troubles because of DNAT 3/ if you have done `modprobe nf_nat_ftp` (but see https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/secure-use-of-helpers/ it's activated by default now) then netfilter will avoid anyway bad interactions for the local ftp client case, whatever the ports in use.

Comment: tnx @A.B for your valuable response.